# Using the results of an aggregate function in a calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to use the result of an aggregate function in a calculation. Let's say I need to use a MAX function and add it to another field.

One way of doing it I found was to use a derived table:

```
SELECT DerivedTable.MaxValue, TableA.Col2 + DerivedTable.MaxValue FROM (
SELECT ID, MAX(Col1) AS MaxValue FROM TableA
) As DerivedTable 
INNER JOIN TableA ON DerivedTable.ID=TableA.ID
```

Is there any way to do it in a single Select statement?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005+ you can use `OVER()`:

```
SELECT MAX(Col1) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) MaxValue, 
       Col2 + MAX(Col1) OVER(PARTITION BY ID)
FROM TableA
```

Comment: He don't want to use the max value for each ID but overall(imho).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Really?, but he is using a derived table in wich he joins by `ID`. Anyway, that is easily fixed by removing the `PARTITION BY` and just leave `MAX(Col1) OVER()`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I figured that it wasn't you, it was more of a rethorical question :-)

Comment: @Lamak . . . I didn't downvote.  But I also haven't upvoted.  Could you please replace `(partition by id)` with `()` so it is correct and can be upvoted?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I would if I thought that that is what op wants. But since the question is joining his derived table by `ID` I'm assuming that this is what s/he wants. Until further clarification I won't modify my answer

Comment: @Lamak . . . Good enough for me to upvote.  I should've caught that discrepancy earlier.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No problem, I still want that op explains what he really expects as a result

Answer (score 0):

This uses a subselect instead of an outright derived table.

```
select TableA.Col2 + (select max(col1) from tablea t2 where t2.id = tablea.id group by t2.id)
    from TableA
```